# POST data then navigate to a new page and persist said data in Rails, without using the database?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm aware POST requests aren't meant for navigation but I just want to check if what I've been tasked with is possible.

I have a page in my Rails app - let's call it `cars#index`.  I'm required to make a selection of cars on this page, then submit the selection and be taken to a new page for `car_sales`, with my selection listed in another table.

I have a table which I can make a selection of cars, and then want to POST this data, rendering a new page at `car_sales#new` - with a list of my previously selected cars.

Is this even possible?

```
   # POST car_sales#new

   def new
    @cars = Car.where(id: selected_car_id_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
   end
```

Normally, you would POST to a create action, which would then redirect to some other page which would query your cars which were persisted in the database.  The difference here is I don't want to persist in the DB yet.

I've got as far as POSTing the data from my `cars#index` page, except what's returned in the network tab is the HTML for the `car_sales#new` page - i.e. the browser stays on the same page but it doesn't redirect.

Can someone provide a technical reason why this happens?

Here's my index method though don't think it's relevant here:-

```
   # GET cars#index

   def index
    @cars = Car.all
   end
```

Comment: Maybe I've not explained something if you're asking for this, but I don't think the index method is at all relevant here?  I'm wanting to render data in the new action. I've added the index anyway.

Comment: Right, but it's not redirecting to the NEW page and displaying the POSTed data.  My question is that I assume this is not possible to do.

Comment: Exactly.  So that confirms I'd probably need another action - and regardless, I wouldn't be able to persist posted params if I POST them to NEW and redirect to some other INDEX.  I think my question is quite clear.

Comment: You could definitely persist the params -- but you are doing absolutely nothing to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to acheive by just adding an additional POST route.

```
resources :car_sales do
  post :new
end
```

```
# GET  /car_sales/new
# POST /car_sales/new
def new
  # @todo rewrite so it checks if param is present.
  @cars = Car.where(id: selected_car_id_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

```
<%= form_with(url: new_car_sales_path, method: :post, data: { turbo: false }) do |form| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

However it really just begs the question "But why?". You don't need to use `POST` for a form submission that's idempotent. You can just use the standard GET route.

> Normally, you would POST to a create action, which would then redirect to some other page which would query your cars which were persisted in the database. The difference here is I don't want to persist in the DB yet.

There is nothing forcing you to persist anything in response to a form submission. That is just convention. Nor do you actually need to persist anything as what you want to do is simply render the view with additional inputs.

Parameters can also be forwarded either through the query string or the session - if you actually need it (you don't).

> I've got as far as POSTing the data from my cars#index page, except what's returned in the network tab is the HTML for the car_sales#new page - i.e. the browser stays on the same page but it doesn't redirect.

You're expecting the wrong thing. A form submission doesn't cause a redirect. It's a GET/POST request to the server and the server can respond to it however it wants.

In your case the controller is implicitly rendering a view in response and sending the default `200 - OK` status code. If you actually wanted a redirect (you don't) the server needs to respond with a `3XX` status code and a location header which you do with `redirect_to`.

As to why the client isn't rendering the new view than I can only guess that the request is being sent as a XHR request or that you're not actually sending the correct request or rendering what you think you are.

Comment: Thanks - you've understood my question.  I do in fact need a POST.  The list of ids I need to persist are so large that they exceed the max size of a query param, so GET is out of the question.  Session might be the best option, though I'd need an additional route to set the session and do the redirect afterwards.  When you say it's almost guaranteed to be Turbo - I specifically ensured it wasn't - the response came back with just HTML, not something wrapped in a turbo tag.

Comment: Again you don't actually need to persist anything and I highly doubt that you need to use POST. You're just overcomplicating something which is basically just the user submitting a form and rendering a customized response. This is exactly the same as for example a search form.

Comment: As to why its not redirecting - check the browser console if the request is being sent as an XHR request. If it is then find out why - it could be Rails UJS also. Did you intentially use the Rails 4 tag?

Comment: Possibly UJS I think.  I don't understand why you say I don't need to persist anything?  I'm trying to render a new page with items selected on a previous page.  I also need to be able to do server side search/filtering on this new page - so my NEW action does need the persisted ids.  A session is the only way I can see to do this, aside from saving the selection in a new database table.

Comment: Because you don't. The user submits the form and then you render the page in response. The params the user selects in the form are sent either via the form body or query string parameters.

Comment: You seem stuck on the idea that there is some kind of redirect supposted to happen when there isn't and you don't need one. Submitting a form doesn't cause a redirect - the rails convention where you redirect after a successful form submission does.

Comment: Possibly the fact that I was getting an HTML response in the network tab but the page wasn't changing, is what was confusing me about the redirect.